# Help! Trying reduce icon size in Disco Dingo made my desktop freeze

Tags: gnome-shell, 19.04, desktop-icons

Guys I am able to login into ubuntu without a problem but after the login I am welcomed with my empty desktop, the wallpaper and the side bar icons. Except it has missing desktop icons. The cursor is moving but no highlighting on mouse over, nothing is clickable, keyboard not doing anything (tried bringing up terminal). Even the time on the status bar doesn't update once after the boot up

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVL9X.jpg

I have recently updated my Ubuntu to 19.04 (Disco Dingo). Its been dual booted with windows for quite a while, but the update was installed yesterday. I am using a Lenovo Ideapad

After the update I noticed the desktop icons are made quite large in the update (I used Bionic Beaver before this) so decided to make it a tad bit smaller (That's where I messed up) and looked up online for help. Found a step by step post on this blog:

http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2019/05/change-desktop-icons-size-ubuntu-19-04/

It said this tiny code would help me do so. It basically just opened a notepad where I could edit the values.

sudo gedit /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/desktop-icons@csoriano/prefs.js

So I edited the values and changed the value of the mouse over highlighter to ZERO (because that's what was making all the icons to spread apart rather than being close to each other)

Now I am left with something like just a screenshot of my desktop with all desktop icons missing and side bar icons there. Help would really be appreciated!

Cheers

Comment: Not sure if it's related, but you should [never run a GUI application with `sudo`](https://askubuntu.com/q/270006/480481) (e.g. `sudo gedit`).

Comment: @promsky I am new to ubuntu. In such cases where commands require permissions. What should I better do ?

Comment: Check the link in my previous comment, there are some alternatives like `sudo -H gedit` instead of `sudo gedit`.

Comment: Sure Thanks! I will visit the link